# PhoneGap app that utilizes CodeIgniter and MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter, cordova

I have created web application where I used CodeIgniter for secure form, also I have connect with remote MySQL database.

Now I want create mobile app in PhoneGap. I never used it before so I need to ask about a few things.

1. Can I create in PhoneGap php folder and there make PHP file to connect with my database?
2. How to secure form in my mobile app? Can I use CodeIgniter? If yes: how? Just paste CodeIgniter files to phonegap www folder?

I hear something about AngularJS. Can I use it for secure form? maybe CodeIgniter is not necessary?

Sorry for noob questions ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have created **is** called a Web App.

What you you would like to create with PhoneGap is a **Hybrid App**.?

PhoneGap/Cordova framework contains a **Browser**   and has plugins that can be added to access **Native** features which can be **accessed through JavaScript**.
 
Native features of the phone like Contacts, Calendar, GeoLocation, Accelormeter etc. Which is not possible when you use a Mobile Browser. Hence the name **Hybrid App**
 
(Using the term Browser for simplicity sake. A more appropriate term is **Webview** container.)
So any web application that uses HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript will work with PhoneGap/Cordova.
PhoneGap allows you to create Hybrid Apps for all the platforms Android/IOS (Iphone)/Windows/BlackBerry.

Now comming to your questions.
Q1)
You do not need to create any folder.
You just need to point the startup (index.html) file to your Webserver address.

Q2) 
As informed earlier your Hybrid app is a like a Browser(with additional features) so the same codeigniter code for securing the form will work.

*I hear something about AngularJS. Can I use it for secure form? maybe Codeigniter is not necessary?*
Codeigniter is a **Serverside** scripting tool which is used for processing server side request.
AngularJS is a **client side JavaScript framework** which is used mostly to create a **SPA** ( Singe Page Application) web application.
SPA web application relies heavily on AJAX

**EDIT 1:**
In the **index.html** file which will be located in the `assets\www` directory you need to add the following code in the **head** tag.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the Codova API
     window.location="http://your.website"; }
</script>
```

You also need to tell Cordova that it is safe to load your website in the **config.xml** properties (you can remove the subdomains part if you don't have any)

```
<access origin="http://your.website" subdomains="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

I don't understand just one thing. 

> You do not need to create any folder.
You just need to point the startup (index.html) file to your Webserver address.

How I can do this?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand.. Where I should put php files ? in assets\www? Now I'm really confused how to connect with mysql

Comment: your **php** files will reside on the webserver. for e.g assuming that you have a **index.php** file on your webserver then `window.location="http://your.website/index.php"` would start your application in the hybrid app. Your Hybrid app is like a web browser, think from that point of view and hopefully clear your confusion.

Comment: can i just put codeigniter folder inside phonegap project and direct it locally using above method ?